# Remove the CSS style loaded from Static Resource when LWC is closed

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I have imported a CSS library from a static resource file in my LWC using loadstyle as below.

## LWC.js

```
import {LightningElement, api} from 'lwc';
import modal from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/modal';
import {loadStyle} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';


 connectedCallback() {

    Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, modal + '/modal.css') //specified filename
        ])
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Loaded style');
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('errror' + error);
            
        });

     }
```

The 'modal' file imported changes the standard Modal pop up CSS properties. However after closing this LWC, I expect the CSS properties also being removed. However this doesn't happen. The same CSS properties get applied to other Modal pop ups in the page. How can I unload this style without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have faced the same issue and there is a working way to handle this.

1. Add a JavaScript file to your Static Resource or create a new one if yours isn't of the application/zip type.
2. Load the JavaScript file from the Static Resource when you need to remove the stylesheet.

When you add a stylesheet from a Static Resource it adds a stylesheet to the whole html page. It's added to the `head` of the page and looks like this:

```
<link href="/resource/RESOURCE_ID/modal/modal.css" charset="utf-8" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Therefore, you can access it and manipulate as you want using JavaScript.

**Below is the example of how it works**

Imagine a scenario where you need to remove the custom styling from the Static Resource on the press of a button.

**LWC HTML**

```
<template>
    <button onclick={removeStylesheet}></button>
</template>
```

**LWC JavaScript**

```
import {LightningElement, api} from 'lwc';
import modal from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/modal';
import {loadStyle} from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

...

removeStylesheet() {
    Promise.all([loadScript(this, modal + "/removeStylesheet.js")]);
}

...
```

**Static Resource JavaScript file**

```
const STYLESHEET_NAME = "modal";
function removeStylesheet() {
    const cssLinks = document.querySelectorAll("link");
    if (cssLinks) {
        cssLinks.forEach((link) => {
            const href = link.href;
            if (href && href.includes(STYLESHEET_NAME)) {
                link.remove();
            }
        });
    }
}

removeStylesheet();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are overriding the standard slds classes for Modal, it will affect all Modals. Instead of using loadStyle for styling the Modal use [Styling Hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/). With Styling Hooks you can apply different styles to different Modals.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. but the properties I want to change is not in the list of styling hooks.. It has to be via 3rd party CSS library..

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove a CSS once imported. You'll need to specify a more specific selector (e.g. ".my-modal.slds-whatever-class").